# Selenium throws org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: null value in entry: message=null intermittantly, running on threads

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I have a selenium test suite, which runs using testng threads.

Currently running with 4 threads.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="multi-package" parallel="tests" thread-count="3">

<parameter name="name1" value="true"/>
<parameter name="name2" value="2177"/>
...
...

    <test name="user-tests">
        <parameter name="package" value="web.package.one"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.x.y.TestDriver"/>
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="user-tests">
        <parameter name="package" value="web.package.two"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.x.y.TestDriver"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
....
....

</suite>
```

There are about 83 selenium tests that run for about 25 mins in the test suite.

This test run, at different tests classes throws the below exception.

```
INFO  [TestNG-tests-3] com.test.org.scripts.web.test_group.MyTestClass  - Starting Test Case : View Contacts - Contact Address ID 15783716
INFO  [TestNG-tests-3] com.test.org.accelerators.WebDriverActions  - Refreshing page
ERROR [TestNG-tests-3] com.test.org.accelerators.WebDriverActions  - org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: null value in entry: message=null
Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-6', revision: '5f43a29cfc'
System info: host: 'ABCDEFG001', ip: '100.123.2.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_202'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 92.0.4515.159, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 92.0.4515.107 (87a818b10553..., userDataDir: /tmp/.com.google.Chrome.v00G52}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:46528}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://10.0.15.67:5555/sessio..., se:cdpVersion: 92.0.4515.159, se:vnc: ws://10.0.15.67:5555/sessio..., se:vncEnabled: true, se:vncLocalAddress: ws://localhost:7900/websockify, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: a32a3ff6dc8ccdd65ee51ab01e76ba27
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:196)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:129)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:160)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:582)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:639)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:643)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteNavigation.refresh(RemoteWebDriver.java:945)
    at com.test.org.accelerators.WebDriverActions.refreshPage(WebDriverActions.java:1177)
    at com.test.org.scripts.web.test_group.MyTestClass.sortContactsTest(MyTestClass.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:661)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.access$000(SuiteRunner.java:39)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$SuiteWorker.run(SuiteRunner.java:414)
    at org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadUtil$1.call(ThreadUtil.java:52)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I am running the Selenium test on Selenium grid on Docker running on Jenkins. The Selenium versions I use there are .

- selenium/hub:4.0.0-rc-1-prerelease-20210823
- selenium/node-chrome:4.0.0-rc-1-prerelease-20210823

To make the problem worse every time this happens in different points of the test run. But it seems when that happens its applied to a single test class and the rest of the test continue as expected.

The exception throws at a code line it refreshes the web page.

```
  webDriver.navigate().refresh();
```

Can anyone help me on this? IS this a known defect?

Answer (score 1):

This one requires 2gb of shared memory in node,
better reduce the thread count and please double check the browser is unique for each testcases.

Still not working, use the following compose file

```
    version: '3'
services:
  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:4.0.0-beta-3-prerelease-20210319
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
 
  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:4.0.0-beta-3-prerelease-20210319
    ports:
      - "4442:4442"
      - "4443:4443"
      - "4444:4444"
```

Comment: and do 
docker-compose -f <filename.yml> scale chrome=10

so you will have 10 chrome at the time